# There is a number, the second digit of which is smaller than its first digit by 4, and if the number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

There is a number, the second digit of which is smaller than its first digit by 4, and if the number was divided by the digit's sum, the remainder would be 7.

Actually I know the answer is 623
I found it by using computer program which checks the conditions for all numbers but I wanted to know if there is a mathematical way to slove this problem.

Comment: Do you know how many digits are in the number?  I would expect there to be many solutions with more digits.

Comment: Yes there are but only 1 number which is 3 digit. Can we solve it using some equations and not by trying every number from 0 to 1000

Comment: Fun fact: When I write my answer, I didn't know whether it was going to work... Just try it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-digit case is impossible, since $4\not \equiv7 \mod 4$

Two-digit case: write number as $10(a+4)+a$.

$$10(a+4)+a \equiv 7 \mod (2a+4)$$

$$11a\equiv -33 \mod 2a+4$$

$$a+3 \equiv 0 \mod 2a+4$$

$$2(a+3) \equiv 2 \not \equiv 0 \mod 2a+4$$

Therefore, two-digit is impossible.

Three-digit case: Write number as $100(a+4)+10a+b$.

$$100(a+4)+10a+b\equiv 7 \mod (2a+b+4)$$

$$110a+b+400 \equiv 7 \mod (2a+b+4)$$

$$108a+396\equiv7 \mod (2a+b+4)$$

$$108a+389\equiv 0\mod (2a+b+4)$$

When $a=1$,

$$497\equiv 0 \mod b+6$$

Since $497=7\times 71$, $b+6=7$. However, we "do not want that", since the modulo must be greater than 7. "Remainder = 7" $\implies$ "Modulo > 7"

When $a=2$,

$$605 \equiv 0 \mod b+8$$

$605 = 5 \times 11^2$. Therefore, we can take $b+8=11 \implies b=3$.

Therefore our final answer is $\fbox{623}$.

Comment: Thankyou, thanks a lot I really appreciate your time and help

Comment: @user766974 would you mind accepting the answer if it helps? Thank you! (the tick)

Comment: Sorry I didn't knew that this is me first time asking a question 

Answer (score 0):

You have $6$ possibilities for the two first digits:  $a_1a_2=40,51,62,73,84,95$ and you can verify that the number cannot have two digits. Then you try with $3$ digits keeping in mind that the number minus $7$ is a multiple of $a_1+a_2+a_3$ so you have
$$\frac{a_1a_2a_3-7}{a_1+a_2+a_3}=entero$$
(1) $\dfrac{400+a_3-7}{4+a_3}=\dfrac{393+a_3}{4+a_3}$.  You have to verify with the nine possible values of $a_3$; in other words you must to see if some of the nine following quotiens is an integer:
$$\dfrac{393}{4},\dfrac{394}{5},\dfrac{395}{6},\dfrac{396}{7},\dfrac{397}{8},\cdots,\dfrac{402}{13}$$

(2)Proving now with $51a_3$ you find $\dfrac{510+a_3-7}{6+a_3}=\dfrac{503+a_3}{6+a_3}$ and
for $a_3=1$ you find an apparent solution since $\dfrac{504}{7}=72$. However the number $511$ is exactement divisible by $5+1+1$ so it must be discarded.

(3) Proving with $62a_3$ by the same procedure you'll find your given solution $623$.

Comment: I think there's still quite a lot of trial and error for this one

Comment: For this kind of problems there are not direct techniques to apply.

Comment: You can use mods to at least reduce the problem to dividing and factorising, shown in my solution